# How did theta become equal to 3pi/4 here?

Tags: polar-coordinates

How did theta become equal to 3π/4 in this particular example?

> Find a set of polar coordinates (r,θ) of the cartesian point (-4,4)
>   such that -2π ≤ θ ≤ 2π  and
>
> a.  r > 0 and θ > 0      b.  r > 0 and θ < 0 c.   r < 0 and θ > 0
>   d.  r < 0 and θ < 0
>
> Solution:
>
> x² + y² = r²
>
> r = ±√x² + y² = ±√32 = ±4√2
>
> tanθ = y/x
>
> tanθ = -4/4 = -1 => θ = 3π/4, 
>   since (-4,4) ε QII

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want a number (angle) in the interval $[0,2\pi)$ whose cosine is $\frac{-4}{4\sqrt{2}}$ **and** whose sine is $\frac{4}{4\sqrt{2}}$. There is only one. Cosine negative and sine positive puts us in the second quadrant.

Note that it is not enough to look at the tangent function.

Comment: If I may ask, under what topic of Calculus is this? The values of cosine and sine on a specific value of pi? I just came back to studying Math and as you can see I am hazy on the basics.

Comment: It is not really calculus. The values of the trig functions at "special angles," mainly $0$, $\frac{\pi}{6}$ ($30^\circ$), $\frac{\pi}{4}$ ($45^\circ$), $\frac{\pi}{3}$, $\frac{\pi}{2}$, and their relatives in the other quadrants, are usually covered in high school, in courses sometimes called precalculus, also often earlier. It turns out to be useful to know these, they come up moderately often.

Comment: Thanks! I do have a bad background of Math in high school. I suppose it's time for me to go back to those topics.

Comment: Depends on the kind of calculus course you are taking. If it is of the science/engineering type, then trig functions are important.

Comment: I'm taking up Analytic Geometry and Calculus II, and as I can see from our slides, there's a lot of trig functions in this chapter (Polar Coordinates).

Comment: Polar coordinates are trig functions from beginning to end. Trig identities come up a bit in integration. They also come up (but you have already gone through this, probably) in various "applied" max/min and related rates problems.